# Office 365 SharePoint New View Coulmn Width

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, office

I have a list which has a detail column and comments column. Both of these contain quite a bit of information at any one time.
I have noticed that in the list condenses the information and cuts off the remainder that it cannot fit into the view. I have stretched the column width to fit the information in and then I have gone to 'save view', however as soon as the page refreshes it has reverted back to the original condensed view again.

Is there any way to by default make the columns display more than 5 lines of text or if I widen the columns is there any way to make their new sizes save?

[image: List]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, it's not possible. You'd have to use CSS on that view to make a fixed height of the row.

Comment: Thank you. Is this true even in the new experience on SharePoint?

Comment: @James Unfortunately yes